# FTP credentials needed when using RenderAction for controller method with [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ftp, asp.net-membership, authorization

I often use `@{ Html.RenderAction("Method", "Controller"); }` in my views to embed additional content. Due to a bug, such a `RenderAction` tried to access a controller who was decorated with `[Authorize]` although the user wasn't logged in.

Then something scarry happend: When the page was loaded, the browser opened a form and asked for credentials. The form looked like to one you see when you try to access a password protected directory (via .htaccess).
Via trial and error, I was able to log in - by using the credentials of my admin ftp account. Afterwards the membership code believed that I was logged in (with the user name `[MachineName]\[FTPUserName]`), causing a lot of new bugs (because this account couldn't be associated with an user id by my own code).

While all I had to do was to fix the first bug, I really would like to know why the membership code of asp.net was able to use the FTP credentials for a login and why it tried to do so in the first place.

Additional information: This bug didn't occurred when I debugged the program on my personal computer, only on the web server where I published it.

Please ask if more information is required.

Comment: Which `authentication` mode you use on server?

Comment: @cem: Where can I see this?

Comment: Default value of authentication mode is "Windows", that may cause this. You can check it in web.config, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: No, my authentication mode is "Forms": `<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>`

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because some statics files, images for example, are in a folder that is not visible for everyone. Does the IIS_IUSRS have read access on the directory server (in properties/security of the folder)? Do you have custom rules in your FTP setup that protect some files? That should explain why it works on your computer but not online. It's more an IIS setup problem then a MVC problem.

Comment: The permissions for the partial view don't differ from the ones of the main page (that was accessible without problems) and I didn't create any custom rules. The partial view does not even contain any images, it only displays some data in a table. But thanks for your help anyway!